# Getting the flash object using the DOM

Tags: javascript, flash, embed, movie

I am embedding a flash video using the SWFObject static publishing option. The code is found at: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

I am embedding a youTube video and want a javascript function to start playing the video. I have tried using the document.getObjectById and document.getElementById methods. Neither of these are working. I know that there is a Play() method once I get access to the movie object. I have also added to lines of code from the example:

```
<param swliveconnect='true' />
<param allowscriptaccess='always' />
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the document.getElementById returning?
I use jQuery, you should do the same.

Have a look at the animIntro object at http://www.siqopiz.com and check the main.js script.